# New DF column based on the value of another column. Possible new values obtained by checking the name of pre-existing columns with highest value

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (will call it 'df') with a decent amount of variables (numeric and characters, there are some NAs in there too). Some of the columns hold the grade of a specific school subject, some other columns are not related at all. Each row represents a dude.

I want to create a new one (will call it 'preferedSubject') with values based on a threshold (let's say 0.5) imposed in another column ('Happiness'); where, if the value of this variable is lower than the threshold, the value of 'preferedSubject' for that row will be a string (let's say... '2Cool4School') and, if higher, the value will become the name of the school subject with the highest score from that row. That is, the name of the column with the highest numeric value (while excluding some of the other columns, remember that some of them are not school subjects)

This of course isn't my data; just decided to use it as a basic and (hopefully clear) example of what's going on, for some reason I always find a way to put it in terms of school subjects and students.

The first part of my problem should be easily handled with the ifelse function I believe; that way I can assign a value to 'preferedSubject' depending on whether 'Happyness' is lower than 0.5 or not. 
The part that's causing me trouble is the second one, I cannot find a way to retrieve the name of the column (school subject) with the highest score while excluding some other columns (non school subject) first.

Assuming this is my dataframe:

```r
df <- structure(list(Average = c(7.5, 9, 6, NA), Total = c(22.5, 27, 
18, NA), Happiness = c(0.7, 1, 0.3, 0.5), Math = c(8, 9, 5, 10
), History = c(7, 8, 9, NA), Unrelated1 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 
1L, NA), .Label = c("A. Einstein", "D. DeVito", "M. Curie"), class = "factor"), 
    Chemistry = c(7.5, 10, 4, 7), Unrelated2 = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

### Average Total Happiness Math History  Unrelated1 Chemistry Unrelated2
### 1     7.5  22.5       0.7    8       7   D. DeVito       7.5          M
### 2     9.0  27.0       1.0    9       8    M. Curie      10.0          F
### 3     6.0  18.0       0.3    5       9 A. Einstein       4.0          M
### 4      NA    NA       0.5   10      NA        <NA>       7.0          M
```

I've been playing a little bit with this code I got, which returns the position of the vector given (school subject column names) that has the highest value:

```r
apply(df[, c("Math", "History", "Chemistry")], 1, which.max)
```

Running it in this example returns

```r
[1] 1 3 2 1
```

so 'Math', 'Chemistry', 'History' and 'Math'... indeed the school subjects with the highest score for each individual in the dataframe.

However; since there are other columns, I've not been able to make it work in such a way where I can simply do something like:

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) {
  x[['preferedSubject']] <- ifelse(x[['Happiness']] < 0.5, "2Cool4School", functionthatshouldreturnwhatIasked(x))
  x
})
```

So I expect something like this as output, a new column that checks whether 'Happiness' is higher than 0.5 or not. If so, it's designated value is the name of the column with the higher score (excluding Average, Total, Hapiness, Unrelated1 and Unrelated2); if not, it's designated value it's simply '2Cool4School'

```r
### Average Total Happiness Math History  Unrelated1 Chemistry Unrelated2 preferedSubject
### 1     7.5  22.5       0.7    8       7   D. DeVito       7.5          M            Math
### 2     9.0  27.0       1.0    9       8    M. Curie      10.0          F       Chemistry
### 3     6.0  18.0       0.3    5       9 A. Einstein       4.0          M      2Cool4School
### 4      NA    NA       0.5   10      NA        <NA>       7.0          M            Math
```

I'm a biologist, and pretty new with R; I think I should've started programming in another language but so far I'm loving it. I've done like 2 tutorials already, if anyone's got a good guide/tutorial/site recommendation I'd gladly take it!

Thanks in advance! Really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `ifelse` and `max.col` by replacing `NA`s with 0 and then get index of maximum value in each row.

```
cols <- c("Math", "History", "Chemistry")

df$preferedSubject <- ifelse(df$Happiness >= 0.5, 
         cols[max.col(replace(df[cols], is.na(df[cols]), 0))], "2Cool4School")

df
#  Average Happiness Math History  Unrelated1 Chemistry Unrelated2 preferedSubject
#1     7.5       0.7    8       7   D. DeVito       7.5          M            Math
#2     9.0       1.0    9       8    M. Curie      10.0          F       Chemistry
#3     6.0       0.3    5       9 A. Einstein       4.0          M    2Cool4School
#4      NA       0.5   10      NA        <NA>       7.0          M            Math
```

---

Or using OP's approach with `apply` and `which.max`

```
df$preferedSubject <- ifelse(df$Happiness >= 0.5, 
                    cols[apply(df[cols], 1, which.max)], "2Cool4School")
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you very much. Just tried it with my true dataset and it worked perfectly (had to figure a way to store the 'school subjects' into the 'cols' vector, cause in my data there are way more than just 3 haha). Didn't know about the max.col function, just read about it, gonna figure out why it worked here since the documentation says it works for a numerical matrix. Appreciate your help!